# HTML Tables: Adding a separator presents odd behavior

Tags: html, css-tables

I'm building a table that requires a small separation in between two of the cells. If you run the provided snippet, you'll notice that the last row at the bottom seems to fall out of the formation and not conform to the table in a similar way as its siblings. I'm not entirely sure why. Sorry for the long code sample, the entire thing is needed to re-enact the issue.

```html
<table border="1">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th class="wedge" rowspan="34">
              <div class="wedge-name-container">
                <h3 class="rotate">Vision</h3>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="slice color-See Possibility" rowspan="17">
              <div class="rotate header">See Possibility</div>
            </th>
            <th class="pole name color-Reflection" rowspan="4">
              <div class="rotate">Reflection</div>
            </th>
            <th class="pole modifier color-Reflection" rowspan="4">
              <div class="rotate">Benefits</div>
            </th>
            <td class="statement pole-start">I take time to look back on lessons learned</td>
            <td class="answer pole-start">3</td>
            <td rowspan="4" class="matrix-container">
              <div class="avg benefits mid matrix-bars">
              <p>4.5</p></div>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="statement ">I pause to be curious about new possibilities</td>
            <td class="answer ">5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="statement ">I think things through before I act</td>
            <td class="answer ">6</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="statement ">New reflection benefits</td>
            <td class="answer ">2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="pole name color-Change" rowspan="4">
              <div class="rotate">Change</div>
            </th>
            <th class="pole modifier color-Change" rowspan="4">
              <div class="rotate">Benefits</div>
            </th>
            <td class="statement pole-start">I look for ways to improve or make things better</td>
            <td class="answer pole-start">3</td>
            <td rowspan="4" class="matrix-container">
              <div class="avg benefits high matrix-bars">
              <p>5</p></div>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="statement ">I can easily pivot to meet emerging opportunities</td>
            <td class="answer ">3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="statement ">I put new things in place to keep things fresh and different</td>
            <td class="answer ">5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="statement ">New change benefits</td>
            <td class="answer ">6</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="spacer" rowspan="1">
            <td class="sideborder-none sm">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="pole name color-Reflection pole-start" rowspan="4">
              <div class="rotate">Reflection</div>
            </th>
            <th class="pole modifier color-Reflection" rowspan="4">
              <div class="rotate">Overuses</div>
            </th>
            <td class="statement  pole-start" style="background: #EBEBEB;">I can overthink plans and possibilities</td>
            <td class="answer  pole-start" style="background: #EBEBEB;">2</td>
            <td class="avg overuses mid" rowspan="4">
              4.5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="statement  " style="background: #EBEBEB;">I think of great ideas that I don't follow through on</td>
            <td class="answer  " style="background: #EBEBEB;">1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="statement  " style="background: #EBEBEB;">I delay making decisions until things are crystal clear</td>
            <td class="answer  " style="background: #EBEBEB;">4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="statement last-item " style="background: #EBEBEB;">New reflection overuses</td>
            <td class="answer last-item " style="background: #EBEBEB;">5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="pole name color-Change pole-start" rowspan="4">
              <div class="rotate">Change</div>
            </th>
            <th class="pole modifier color-Change" rowspan="4">
              <div class="rotate">Overuses</div>
            </th>
            <td class="statement  pole-start" style="background: #EBEBEB;">I spend time changing things that don't really need to be changed</td>
            <td class="answer  pole-start" style="background: #EBEBEB;">2</td>
            <td class="avg overuses high" rowspan="4">
              5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="answer  " style="background: #EBEBEB;">3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="statement  " style="background: #EBEBEB;">I can neglect to appreciate what is working</td>
            <td class="answer  " style="background: #EBEBEB;">3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="statement last-item " style="background: #EBEBEB;">New change overuses</td>
            <td class="answer last-item " style="background: #EBEBEB;">3</td>
          </tr>
          <!-- Spacer row -->
          <tr class="spacer">
            <td class="sideborder-none md">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="sideborder-none md">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="sideborder-none md">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="sideborder-none md">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="sideborder-none md">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="slice color-Provide Inspiration" rowspan="17">
              <div class="rotate header">Provide Inspiration</div>
            </th>
            
            <th class="pole name color-Challenge" rowspan="4">
              <div class="rotate">Challenge</div>
            </th>
            <th class="pole modifier color-Challenge" rowspan="4">
              <div class="rotate">Benefits</div>
            </th>
            <td class="statement pole-start">I pursue excellence by stretching limits</td>
            <td class="answer pole-start">3</td>
            <td rowspan="4" class="matrix-container">
              <div class="avg benefits mid matrix-bars">
              <p>4.5</p></div>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="statement ">I challenge people to go where they haven't gone before</td>
            <td class="answer ">4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="statement ">I help people think bigger and look beyond what they can see</td>
            <td class="answer ">5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="statement ">New challenge benefits</td>
            <td class="answer ">6</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="pole name color-Exude Competence" rowspan="4">
              <div class="rotate">Exude Competence</div>
            </th>
            <th class="pole modifier color-Exude Competence" rowspan="4">
              <div class="rotate">Benefits</div>
            </th>
            <td class="statement pole-start">I share my knowledge and opinions with assuredness</td>
            <td class="answer pole-start">6</td>
            <td rowspan="4" class="matrix-container">
              <div class="avg benefits mid matrix-bars">
              <p>4.75</p></div>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="statement ">I demonstrate confidence in my expertise</td>
            <td class="answer ">6</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="statement ">I show up strong and capable</td>
            <td class="answer ">4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="statement ">New exude competence benefits</td>
            <td class="answer ">3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="spacer" rowspan="1">
            <td class="sideborder-none sm">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="pole name color-Challenge pole-start" rowspan="4">
              <div class="rotate">Challenge</div>
            </th>
            <th class="pole modifier color-Challenge" rowspan="4">
              <div class="rotate">Overuses</div>
            </th>
            <td class="statement  pole-start" style="background: #EBEBEB;">I can push people too far too fast</td>
            <td class="answer  pole-start" style="background: #EBEBEB;">1</td>
            <td class="avg overuses low" rowspan="4">
              2.5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="statement  " style="background: #EBEBEB;">My drive for excellence can create stress for others</td>
            <td class="answer  " style="background: #EBEBEB;">2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="statement  " style="background: #EBEBEB;">I move on to the next thing without taking time to celebrate</td>
            <td class="answer  " style="background: #EBEBEB;">4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="statement last-item " style="background: #EBEBEB;">New challenge overuses</td>
            <td class="answer last-item " style="background: #EBEBEB;">3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="pole name color-Exude Competence pole-start" rowspan="4">
              <div class="rotate">Exude Competence</div>
            </th>
            <th class="pole modifier color-Exude Competence" rowspan="4">
              <div class="rotate">Overuses</div>
            </th>
            <td class="statement  pole-start" style="background: #EBEBEB;">I point out what's right without being impeded by other people's feelings</td>
            <td class="answer  pole-start" style="background: #EBEBEB;">2</td>
            <td class="avg overuses low" rowspan="4">
              2.25</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="statement  " style="background: #EBEBEB;">I make sure people are aware of my expertise and opinion</td>
            <td class="answer  " style="background: #EBEBEB;">3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="statement  " style="background: #EBEBEB;">When I've made up my mind, I give little credence to other's ideas and suggestions</td>
            <td class="answer  " style="background: #EBEBEB;">2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="statement last-item " style="background: #EBEBEB;">New exude competence overuses</td>
            <td class="answer last-item " style="background: #EBEBEB;">2</td>
          </tr>
          <!-- Spacer row -->
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake, I had to bring the rowspan on the first th up to 36 to match the new total rowspan value needed. ughhh

The solution to my problem. Note, make sure the rowspans are right.

```html
<tr>
    <th class="wedge" rowspan="36">
      <div class="wedge-name-container">
        <h3 class="rotate">People</h3>
      </div>
    </th>
    <th class="slice color-Demonstrate Care" rowspan="17">
      <div class="rotate header">Demonstrate Care</div>
    </th>
    <th class="pole name color-Relationships Focus" rowspan="4">
      <div class="rotate">Relationships Focus</div>
    </th>
```

Comment: post the code with it :) I'd like to check something.

Comment: Well there goes 20 mins of my life :)) But been there done that myself...

Comment: @Mech updated this post with my solution, really just a rowspan issue.

Comment: @ikiK haha I'm so sorry.